# Serialize JSON with indentation from XQuery

Tags: json, xquery, marklogic

From XQuery on MarkLogic, is it possible to serialize a JSON node with indentation?

It is possible to do it with XML using `xdmp:quote()`, but using the same code with a JSON node returns a long, flat string, with no indentation.

Comment: I'm not sure if MarkLogic has adopted XQuery 3.1's JSON serialization method or not, but if so, calling `serialize($my-json, map { "method": "json", "indent": true() })` will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I also have a function I use to pretty print JSON with XQuery. It originally came [from here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/writing-json-pretty-printer-kurt-cagle/) but I've made a number of bug fixes and enhancements to it:

```
declare namespace pp = "http://marklogic.com/ns/prettyprint";

declare function pp:pretty-print($str as xs:string) as xs:string {
  let $s1 := fn:replace($str,'(\{|\(|\[)','$1&#13;')
  let $s2 := fn:replace($s1,'(\}|\)|\])','&#13;$1')
  let $s3 := fn:replace($s2,',',',&#13;')
  let $tokens := fn:tokenize($s3,'&#13;')
  let $map := map:new((map:entry("index",0),map:entry("buffer","")))
  let $_ := 
    for $token in $tokens return 
      (
      for $new-index in (0 to map:get($map,"index")-1) 
      return 
          if ($new-index eq map:get($map,"index")-1 and fn:matches($token,'[\}]')) then () else map:put($map,"buffer",map:get($map,"buffer")||"&#9;"),
          map:put($map,"buffer",map:get($map,"buffer")||fn:normalize-space($token)||'&#13;'),
          if (fn:matches($token,'[\{|\(|\[]')) then 
            map:put($map,"index",map:get($map,"index") + 1)
          else if (fn:matches($token,'[\)|\]]')) then  
            map:put($map,"index",map:get($map,"index") - 1)
          else if (fn:matches($token,'[\}]')) then  
            map:put($map,"index",map:get($map,"index") - 1)
          else () 
      )
   return map:get($map,"buffer")
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried a few different ways, but only a custom function seems to do the trick:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare namespace fx = "http://www.functx.com";
declare function fx:repeat-string
  ( $stringToRepeat as xs:string? ,
    $count as xs:integer )  as xs:string {

   string-join((for $i in 1 to $count return $stringToRepeat),
                        '')
 } ;

declare function local:stringify($nodes, $indent) {
  local:stringify($nodes, $indent, 0)
};

declare function local:stringify($nodes, $indent, $level) {
  let $indent-string := fx:repeat-string(" ", $indent * $level)
  for $node in $nodes
  return (
    $indent-string
    || (
      if (name($node) != "" and not($node/.. instance of array-node())) then
        ("&quot;" || name($node) || "&quot;: ")
      else ""
    ) || (
      typeswitch ($node)
      case object-node() return (
        "{&#10;" || string-join(local:stringify($node/node(), $indent, $level + 1), ",&#10;") || "&#10;" || $indent-string || "}"
      )
      case array-node() return (
        "[&#10;" || string-join(local:stringify($node/node(), $indent, $level + 1), ",&#10;") || "&#10;" || $indent-string || "]"
      )
      case text() return (
        "&quot;" || replace(replace(replace($node, "&#10;", "\\n"), "&#13;", "\\r"), "&quot;", '\\"') || "&quot;"
      )
      default return xdmp:quote($node)
    )
  )
};

let $json := object-node{
  "text": "abc",
  "number": 1,
  "boolean": true(),
  "null": null-node{},
  "array": array-node{
    "abc",
    1,
    true(),
    null-node{},
    object-node{ "foo": "bar&#10;&#13;&quot;&apos;mitswa" }
  },
  "object": object-node{
    "text": "abc",
    "number": 1,
    "boolean": true(),
    "null": null-node{},
    "array": array-node{
      "abc",
      1,
      true(),
      null-node{},
      object-node{ "foo": "bar" }
    }
  }
}
return (
  xdmp:quote($json, map:entry("indentUntyped", "yes")),
  xdmp:to-json-string($json),
  xdmp:javascript-eval("JSON.stringify(json, null, 2);", map:entry("json", $json)),
  local:stringify($json, 2)
)
```

HTH!